pip not installing all folders of a package
When doing pip3.12 install google and running import google I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'.
When checking the libraries folder (/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/) I can see that there is a folder named google-3.0.0.dist-info and another one named googlesearch but no folder named google.
I tried using venv and reinstalling the package multiple times with no luck.

That's because the module is called googlesearch (https://python-googlesearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I was installing the wrong library (I wanted google-api-core not googlesearch) as @Anya Shenanigans mentioned

pip doesn't just install folders. It uses a wheel file that the creator of the package makes and follows the wheel's orders to install the package.
if you want to install the full project, it's better to go into pypi and find the full project (in this case, https://pypi.org/project/google/#files is what you're looking for)
